Tracking URL Copy in Javascript
I am creating a GA4 custom event tag and the code below works when someone copies any text on the page. However, I only want to track when someone copies the full URL of the current page in the browser. Any ideas on how to modify the script?
Thank you!
   <script>
    document.addEventListener('copy', function(){
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    window.dataLayer.push({
    'event': "copyText",
    'copiedText': selection
   });
   });
   </script>


you can compare the copied text to the current page's URL.

As I said in my comment, you can try to compare the copied text to the current page's URL.
<script>
document.addEventListener('copy', function() {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    var currentUrl = window.location.href; // Gets the full URL of the current page

    if (selection === currentUrl) { // Compares the copied text to the full URL
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': "copyUrl",
            'copiedText': selection
        });
    }
});
</script>

Also users might unintentionally copy the URL with leading or trailing white space. so use the trim()
if (selection.trim() === currentUrl.trim()) {
    // ... dataLayer
}

and to test, you can add a try catch:
document.addEventListener('copy', async function() {
    try {
        const clipboardText = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
        if (clipboardText === window.location.href) {
            window.dataLayer.push({
                'event': "copyUrl",
                'copiedText': clipboardText
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to read clipboard contents: ', error);
    }
});


Hey Davi... Yes, the code you provided works! But I'm not sure how to modify it for the 'workaround' you were referring to since the copied URL will only be from the address bar. The URL won't be anywhere on the page itself. Could you give a code for the workaround? Thank you!
